# Differential Equation with Substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this Differential Equation:

$$(2x^2 + y^2) \frac{dy}{dx} = 2xy$$

and I solved it by substituting $y=vx$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dx} (x +v)$

I found a result of $y^2(\ln(y) +C)=x^2$, but since it must be an implicit solution for $y$ I don't know whether I should leave it in this form. Also I hope I didn't do anything wrong in the proccess. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You can leave it in the implicit form!

Comment: @AlexR: I know that it can be solved explicitly in terms of Lambert W function! But it is beyond what he was asked to do and it depends on his knowledge of the Lambert W function!

Comment: @science: I read "can't" for some reason, sorry!

Comment: @AlexR.: No problem!

Answer (score 2):

There is a typing mistake in :
$y=vx$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}\neq\frac{dv}{dx} (x +v)$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=v+x\frac{dv}{dx}$$
With this, you got to :
$$x^2=y^2(c+ln(y))$$
That's OK. You can let it on the implicit form (or an equivalent form).

One can express $y(x)$ thanks to a special function called Lambert W function.
$$y=\pm \frac{\sqrt 2 \: x}{\sqrt{W(C x^2)}}$$

Comment: Yes indeed that was a typing mistake. Thank you for this, although I haven't been introduced to the Lambert W function yet. Thank you very much!

Comment: @ rogerdom : You are wellcome. Information about the Lambert W function can be found in :http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html and more general information on the use of special functions : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14623310/Safari-on-the-country-of-the-Special-Functions-Safari-au-pays-des-fonctions-spéciales . The Lambert W function is commented p.24 and in Table 4, p.33 .

Answer (score 0):

here is another way to solve $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2xy}{2x^2 + y^2}.$$  split the differential equation into two as $$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac y{2x^2+y^2}, \frac{dt}{dx}=2x.$$

solving for $x,$ we get $$x^2 = t +C. \tag1$$ and the differential equation for $y$ is $$ \frac{dt}{dy} = \frac{2x^2+y^2}{y} = \frac{2(t + C)}{y}  + y.$$ which can be solved as $$ t + C = y^2\ln y +By^2.\tag 2$$ eliminating $t$ between $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives you $$x^2 = y^2 \ln y+By^2, \text{ where  $B$ is an arbitrary constants.  } $$

i can't figure out where i am losing an $\ln y.$

edit: thanks to narasimham. i found the error at the very beginning. i copied the wrong equation. it is good now.

Comment: If one bring back $x^2=y+B\ln(y)-C$ into the ODE one see that your result is not consistent.

Comment: Why don't you test by yourself the solution that you found ? Put it into the ODE and see if it's agree :  unfortunatly, it still doesn't agree.

Comment: @abel RHS Denominator is $ x^2 + y^2  $  or  $  2 x^2 + y^2 $ ?

Comment: @Narasimham, thanks. you are very good at spotting my errors. that error has been bothering me for a while. ok, i will fix it now.